# Storing database credentials — Best Practice for PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, credentials

I’m looking for a best-practice on storing database credentials for use with PDO.
My DB is stored on GoDaddy, and has a couple of hundred users (maybe).
I recently converted from using mysql_* to PDO and after much Googling for an answer I’ve come to the conclusion that no clear, concise method exists.
Currently I use a config.inc file that stores the credentials as;

```
<?php
$strHostName = “10.10.10.10”; 
$strDbName = “dbname”;
$strUserName = “dbuser”;  
$strPassword = “xxx***xxx”;
?>
```

I do the following in my code;

```
<?
….stufff
require_once(‘config.inc’);

$db_found = new PDO("mysql:host=$strHostName;dbname=$strDbName;charset=utf8", $strUserName,     $strPassword, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
…lots more stuff
?>
```

This works fine but I’m concerned about the security of the config.inc file. Is there a preferred method to do this?

Thanks…

Comment: What's wrong with its "security"?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the security unless you got a security risk on your web server. i.e. Someone is trying to hack into server. Only other option I can think of is to use constants.

Comment: I use constants in my database config

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this works really as I haven't tried it, but learned about it the other day so I thought I'd share.

With GoDaddy you can point your primary domain name at a sub-directory, therefore creating a new document root before it, so to speak.

For example, create a new directory called 'application' in your root directory, upload your application's files there and point your domain there (You may need to remove the domain name first and then add it again with the specified directory). You can then include files - your database credentials for example - from before your new document root, which is now not available to the public but available to your application.

**NEW STRUCTURE**

DB Credentials:

```
/home/www/html/someSite/dbCredentials.php
```

Your Website (where primary domain is now pointed):

```
/home/www/html/someSite/application/index.php
```

**EXAMPLE:**

In dbCredentials.php add your credentials:

```
<?php
$strHostName = “10.10.10.10”; 
$strDbName = “dbname”;
$strUserName = “dbuser”;  
$strPassword = “xxx***xxx”;
?>
```

On your web page, include the file and use variables as normal:

```
<?php
require_once ('/home/www/html/someSite/dbCredentials.php');
$db_found = new PDO("mysql:host=$strHostName..........);
?>
```

**SOURCE:**

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4175/specifying-a-new-default-document-root-on-your-hosting-account?pc_split_value=4&countrysite=uk

If you try it, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the password is stored in a file that is either not readable, or accessible from the web.

Storing the password in a `.php` file is considered *safe* because you can not see the contents of a `.php` file from the web (only it's output).

You can also store the file outside of the webroot, which makes the file wholly inaccessible from the web.

Another solution is to use the native webserver ignore rules. Files that start with a `.` like `.password` are hidden on some webservers. Specifically Apache hides all files that start with `.ht`. These depend on webserver vendor though so be cautious.

Storing the password in `config.inc` runs the risk of accidentally exposing the contents when it's in a web-accessible folder.

---

You don't need to worry about someone gaining access to your server and reading the password from the file because you'll have bigger problems: they have access to your server :)

Comment: Also, assuming GoDaddy servers are Linux/Unix, you can set permissions for `config.inc` to be readable only by your user a/c. This hopefully will prevent reading by other users on the server. (For example `600` in octal notation.) Your security is always going to be limited on a shared server. As strong as the weakest link.

Answer (score 0):

You could also place the password as an environment variable on your hosting server and use getenv from your php application to read the password.